# How to list locally-modified/unversioned files using svnkit?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I'm writing a piece of code that, once executed anywhere inside an SVN working copy, locates the root:

```
File workingDirectory = new File(".").getCanonicalFile();
File wcRoot = SVNWCUtil.getWorkingCopyRoot(workingDirectory, true);
```

gets the repository url given this root, builds an `SVNClientManager` given this info and now I'm stuck at how to get a list of anything in the working copy that is not in the repository - this includes locally-modified files, unresolved merges, unversioned files and I'll be happy to hear any anything else I might have missed.

How do I do that ?
This snippet seems to require access to the repository itself, not the WC:

```
clientManager.getLookClient().doGetChanged(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives you local modifications, i.e. it doesn't look at things that have changed in the repository that are not in your working copy

```
static def isModded(SvnConfig svn, File path, SVNRevision rev) {
    SVNClientManager mgr = newInstance(null, svn.username, svn.password)
    logger.debug("Searching for modifications beneath $path.path @ $rev")
    mgr.statusClient.doStatus(path, rev, INFINITY, false, false, false, false, { SVNStatus status ->
        SVNStatusType statusType = status.contentsStatus
        if (statusType != STATUS_NONE && statusType != STATUS_NORMAL && statusType != STATUS_IGNORED) {
            lmodded = true
            logger.debug("$status.file.path --> lmodded: $statusType")
        }
    } as ISVNStatusHandler, null)
    lmodded
}
```

The code I have for this is in groovy but hopefully the use of the svnkit api is obvious enough to work with. SvnConfig is just a local value object containing various details about the repository itself.

Answer (score 10):

```
public static List<File> listModifiedFiles(File path, SVNRevision revision) throws SVNException {
    SVNClientManager svnClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
    final List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    svnClientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(path, revision, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false, false, false, new ISVNStatusHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleStatus(SVNStatus status) throws SVNException {
            SVNStatusType statusType = status.getContentsStatus();
            if (statusType != SVNStatusType.STATUS_NONE && statusType != SVNStatusType.STATUS_NORMAL
                    && statusType != SVNStatusType.STATUS_IGNORED) {
                fileList.add(status.getFile());
            }
        }
    }, null);
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: To include unversioned files I found I had to remove `statusType != SVNStatusType.STATUS_NONE` from the `if` statement